# Non-equilibrium green method based on the Hamiltonian with non-orthogonal basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nanoscience, quantum-transport

I am thinking about one question. If the Hamiltonian matrix is based on the non-orthogonal basis, how to compute the charge conductance with the non-equilibrium green function (NEGF) method.

Suppose the Hamiltonian of the system is denoted by $H$ and the overlap matrix is denoted by $S$. They are written below.
$$\left(\varepsilon_{F}+i\right)\times S-H=\varepsilon^{'}\times S-H=\begin{pmatrix}
\varepsilon^{'}\times S_{ll}-H_{ll}&\varepsilon^{'}\times S_{ls}-H_{ls}&0\\
\varepsilon^{'}\times S_{sl}-H_{sl}&\varepsilon^{'}\times S_{ss}-H_{ss}&\varepsilon^{'}\times S_{sr}-H_{sr}\\0&\varepsilon^{'}\times S_{rs}-H_{rs}&\varepsilon^{'}\times S_{rr}-H_{rr}
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$=\begin{pmatrix}H^{'}_{ll}&H^{'}_{ls}&0\\H^{'}_{sl}&H^{'}_{ss}&H^{'}_{sr}\\0&H^{'}_{rs}&H^{'}_{rr}\end{pmatrix}$$

Here, $\varepsilon_{F}$ is the Fermi energy level of the central scattering zone and $i$ is the imaginary number.

$G_{ll}=\left[H^{'}_{ll}\right]^{-1}$ and $G_{rr}=\left[H^{'}_{r}\right]^{-1}$

$\Gamma_{left}=H^{'}_{sl}\times G_{ll}\times H^{'}_{ls}$ and $\Gamma_{right}=H^{'}_{sr}\times G_{ll}\times H^{'}_{rs}$

Self energy for the left and right leads and the green function  for the scattering zone are written below.
$\Sigma_{left}=i \times \left[\Gamma_{left}-\left(\Gamma_{left}\right)^{+}\right]$ ,  $\Sigma_{right}=i \times \left[\Gamma_{right}-\left(\Gamma_{right}\right)^{+}\right]$,
$G_{ss}^{R}=\left[H^{'}_{ss}-\Gamma_{left}-\Gamma_{right}\right]^{-1}$ and $G_{ss}^{A}=\left(G_{ss}^{R}\right)^{+}$

Then, the charge conductance is written below.

$G_{k}=\frac{2e^{2}}{h}Tr\left[\Sigma_{left}G_{ss}^{A}\Sigma_{right}G_{ss}\right]$

This conductance is only for one single k point in the reciprocal space. The total charge coneuctance is the integral of this single-k-point-conductance over the whole first Brillouin zone.

$G_{total}=\frac{e}{h}\int G_{k}\times \left[f_{(\varepsilon_{F}-\mu_{left})}-f_{(\varepsilon_{F}-\mu_{right})}\right]d_{k}$

where,$f_{(\varepsilon_{F}-\mu_{left})}$ and $f_{(\varepsilon_{F}-\mu_{right})}$ are Fermi-Dirac distribution function for left and right leads with the chemical potential $\mu_{left}$ and $\mu_{right}$ for the left and right leads.

Would anyone please confirm whether my understanding is correct or not? If not, would anyone please help me correct it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would anyone please give me some suggestions on my enquiry or recommend any reference paper, which discusses the calculation with non-orthogonal basis Hamiltonian through the NEGF method? Thank you in advance.